# How to pass total count to the client in pageInfo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

I use `first` `after` and `last` `before` to do pagination.
`hasNextPage` and `hasPreviousPage` are very useful.

But what I need is also the `total count` so that I can calculate and show things like `page 5 of 343 pages` on the client.

Unfortunately that is not part of `pageInfo` even though I have the information on the server site.

Can you please include a `total` field in the `pageInfo` and extend `connectionFromArray` to take in the total `arrayLength` like `connectionFromArraySlice` already does?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`pageInfo` is designed to represent information about the specific page, whereas the total number of items is really a property of the connection itself. We recommend adding a `count` field to the connection. You might query it with:

```
fragment on TodoList {
  tasks(first: 10) {
    count # <-- total number of tasks
    edges { ... }
    pageInfo { ... }
}
```

Relay supports arbitrary fields on a connection, so you're free to name this `count`, `totalCount`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you @Joe Savona

He is absolutely right. Since it took me a moment to figure out how to actually add the property to the connection on the server site I thought I share that here as well:

```
var {connectionType: postsConnection} = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'post',
  nodeType: qlPost,
  connectionFields: () => ({
    totalCount: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: (connection) => connection.totalCount,
      description: `A count of the total number of objects in this connection, ignoring pagination.
This allows a client to fetch the first five objects by passing "5" as the
argument to "first", then fetch the total count so it could display "5 of 83",
for example.`
    }
  })
});
```

Hope that helps others.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  How did you go about assigning a value to connection.totalCount?  I have my project laid out a little different and i am having trouble finding the right place to populate that value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307845/relay-graphql-add-custom-field-to-connection

Answer (score 2):

I used custom `totalCount` field on the connection for a while but it introduced a complexity I did not see at first (when updating connections after a mutation, you have to query it with the same args if you want it to update automatically).

Therefore I went back to having a `count` field next to each of my connections. In your exemple that means:

```
fragment on TodoList {
  taskCount
  tasks {
    edges { ... }
  }
}
```

And I created a small helper that creates it for me: https://github.com/rea-app/relay-connection-count

Comment: I don't know about Relay, but in Apollo you would use the `@connection` directive to exclude parameters such as `limit` or `offset` from the cache key: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/pagination/#the-connection-directive

Comment: This!
When you have the `totalCount` inside your connections beside `pageInfo` and `edges`, it creates a lot of complexity. If a user queries only for `taskCount`, you probably wouldn't want to query db for paginated tasks. So you need to separate them. You can of course check if the `edges` or `pageInfo` is queried or not, but it's not that straightforward most of the times. And if you look at schemas of `withspectrum/spectrum` from GitHub, or Admin API of Shopify, you can see that they use this exact same method. Probably for keeping things separate and simplifying things.